# Selenium- exception instead of boolean value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write a code where I have found the result element visible or not, but I have received an exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']"}
```

Here is my code

```
wd.navigate().refresh();
Thread.sleep(7000);
boolean airbnb = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed();
assertFalse(airbnb, "Airbnb Add will not show After clicking Add one times");
```

Is there any suggestion why element not found showing? if element not found then it should be `false` I am not sure where I mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid an exception, and expensive use of `try - catch`, you can locate the element using `findElements`. If the result list is not empty you can check if the existed element is displayed or not

```
List<WebElement> elements = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']"));
assertFalse(elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0).isDisplayed(), "Airbnb Add will not show After clicking Add one times");
```

Comment: I would argue that in web automation, the "expensiveness" of a `try-catch` is negligible... ;). Having said that, this is the approach that I take and I it's a best practice according to the Java/Selenium docs on `findElement()`.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `try- catch` block or use `throws` Exception to catch the `NoSuchElementException`

```
public void methodName() throws Exception
{
    if(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed())
{
  System.out.println("Element displayed");
} 
}
```

or

```
try
{
if(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed())
{
  System.out.println("Element displayed");
} 
}

catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{
  System.out.println("Element is not displayed");
}
```

Comment: This system working for me.but my question why I use iisDisplayed() if it does not return true...

Comment: By default isDisplayed() true

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not expect the element to be there the following code would throw an exception :

```
boolean airbnb = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed();
```

and your `assert` statement would not even be reached.

You can actually place an expected exception in your code instead of asserting as(in Junit):

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void youtTest() {
   // do whatever you're doing
   Thread.sleep(7000);
   wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']"));
}
```

in `TestNG` the syntax is somehwat like :

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = { NoSuchElementException.class })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with Selenium, you need to use try catch block something like below

```
try
{

        if(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='airbnb-wide-block-search-btn js-airbnb-search-btn']")).isDisplayed())
  {
        //Your code
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
        //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it this way: `IsDisplayed` will work on Object of Type `WebElement`.

here is the clarification

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

found on [findElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)